# How to visualize such PopularCurve entities?

Tags: visualization, entity

The following [command](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Entity.en.html)

```
EntityValue["PopularCurve", "Entities"]
```

returns a long list of `PopularCurve`s:

> {dragon curve, butterfly curve, cannabis curve, Batman-like curve, ...}

Someone from Wolfram showed that these curves look like:
[image]

How to visualize such curves one by one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print them one-by-one you can use

```
Print[Labeled @@ EntityValue[#, {"Image", "Name"}]] & /@ 
  EntityValue["PopularCurve", "Entities"];
```

To cycle through them you can use

```
curves = EntityValue["PopularCurve", "Entities"];
Animate[
  Labeled @@ EntityValue[curve, {"Image", "Name"}], {curve, curves}, 
  AnimationRate -> .1
]
```